# What does "from ... import ..." mean?

Tags: python

```
from sys import argv
from os.path import exists

script, from_file, to_file = argv

print "Copying from %s to %s" % (from_file, to_file)

# we could two on one line too, how?
input = open(from_file)
indata = input.read()

print "The input file is %d bytes long" % len(indata)
print "Does the output file exist? %r" % exists(to_file)
print "Ready, hit return to continue, CTRL-C to abort."

raw_input()

output = open(to_file, 'w')
output.write(indata)

print "Alright, all done."

output.close()
input.close()
```

On the first two lines I have some idea of what is going on, but want to make sure I fully understand it, as this seems like it might be important.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you do `import sys`, you'll get to access the functions and variables in the module sys via `sys.foo` or `sys.bar()`. This can get a lot of typing, especially if using something from submodules (e.g. I often have to access `django.contrib.auth.models.User`). 
To avoid such this redundancy, you can bring one, many or all of the variables and functions into the global scope. `from os.path import exists` allows you to use the function `exists()` without having to prepend it with `os.path.` all the time.

If you'd like to import more than one variable or function from os.path, you could do
`from os.path import foo, bar`.

You can theoretically import all variables and functions with `from os.path import *`, but that is generally discouraged because you might end up overwriting local variables or functions, or hiding the imported ones. See [What's the difference between "import foo" and "from foo import *"?](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/tutor-whats-the-difference-between-import-foo-and-from-foo-import.htm) for an explanation.

Comment: Can you put this in some sort of cooking analogy?  ie making pancakes?

Comment: From Fridge Import Eggs.  A lot easier than saying "Add Kitchen.Fridge.Egg.Yolk[2]" each time

Comment: So from could be pantry, cupboard or fridge... wherever I want to get the ingredients then the import is exactly the ingredient I want - flour milk and/or eggs.

This being easier than actually producing each of the ingredients at time of cooking.

Am I on the right trail here?

Comment: If your `fridge` and `pantry` both contain `pop` , then using: `from fridge import *` followed by `from pantry import *` would overwrite your previous definition of `pop`. You then would think you had used `fridge.pop` but actually have `pantry.pop` which means you have a warm drink :P

Answer (score 9):

```
from module import x
```

means:

Load the module named `module`, but only fetch `x` into the current namespace.

Answer (score 3):

In bonehead terms this means,

```
from USA import iPhone # instead of importing the whole USA for an iPhone you now will just import the iPhone into your program,
```

Why do you need something like this ?

consider this, without the from ... import statement your code will look like this

```
import USA

variableA = USA.iPhone()
```

with the from ... import statement it looks like,

```
from USA import iPhone

variableA = iPhone()
```